# Going through each line in an excel file, and getting ADuser data from them

Tags: loops, csv, powershell, foreach

I'm new to powershell, so this may be an easy to answer question.

So I have an excel file that's full of UserProfileNames. What I want to do it have powershell go through each one, and return the "mail" property. I'm not well versed in powershell foreach commands and variables yet, so my syntax might be all kinds of screwed up, but here is what I've been trying:

```
foreach($PSItem in (import-csv D:\Collaboration-Powershell\upn-that-needs-mail.csv)) {get-aduser $PSItem -Properties mail | select mail}
```

It's just giving me a lot of errors. Can anyone help?

Comment: WHat does the csv file look like? how many columns are there?

Answer (score 0):

here is one possible solution, assuming your csv file has a 'userprofilename' column

```
$accounts = ipcsv 'D:\Collaboration-Powershell\upn-that-needs-mail.csv'

$results = $accounts | % {
    $userprofile = $_.userprofilename
    get-aduser $_.userprofilename -properties mail | select samaccountname, Mail, @{n='UserProfileName';e={$userprofile}}
}

$results | epcsv 'D:\Collaboration-Powershell\upn-that-needs-mail-RESULTS.csv' -not

$results

start 'D:\Collaboration-Powershell\upn-that-needs-mail-RESULTS.csv'
```

or, if you already have the email:

```
$accounts = ipcsv 'D:\Collaboration-Powershell\mail-that-needs-samaccountname.csv'

$results = $accounts | % {
    $email = $_.email
    get-aduser -filter "emailaddress -eq '$email'" -properties mail | select samaccountname, Mail
}

$results
```

Comment: If I were to try and get the 'SamAccountName' property by using the 'mail' property, how would I go about that? I tried altering your code so that it fit the new criteria, but it was a no go. my csv file is only one column with the 'mail' properties and a column header. I can get each samaccountname individually with ///  -Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq 'test@email.com'} -Properties samaccountname | Select samaccountname

Comment: Thank you so much!